# PyCharm remote debugging timeout error possibly by port connection

Tags: debugging, pycharm, timeout, port

I have set up PyCharm for remote debugging with the *Python remote debug server configuration* as described in [PyCharm website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config) on a Mac OS and a Linux (Debian 11.1) machine but I get a

`socket.timeout: timed out`

error.

In this configuration PyCharm emulates a server in the local machine where the PyCharm runs, and then a script running in a remote machine connects to that server. That server in turn tries to connect with the local machine.

It seems that there is a problem in the connection of the PyCharm server with the local machine, and possibly something with the port.

How can I check if the port is open (terminal commands or something else) or if there is something else blocking the connection?

This is the full error message:

```
Could not connect to <public ip address>: 12345
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 458, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
socket.timeout: timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    pydevd_pycharm.settrace(<public ip address>, port=12345, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
  File "<path>/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydevd.py", line 1689, in settrace
    _locked_settrace(
  File "<path>/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydevd.py", line 1745, in _locked_settrace
    debugger.connect(host, port)  # Note: connect can raise error.
  File "<path>/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydevd.py", line 655, in connect
    s = start_client(host, port)
  File "<path>/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 458, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
socket.timeout: timed out
```